# Is it canon that Superman became stronger than Zod because he spent more time exposed to our yellow sun?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

Many posts on different websites mention that Superman became stronger than Zod because he spent more time exposed to our yellow sun.

[Is general Zod more powerful than Superman - Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-General-Zod-more-powerful-than-Superman#:%7E:text=M%20answer%20views-,No.,to%20vaporize%20a%20nearby%20family.)

[How is Superman able to defeat Kryptonians who are better trained and skilled than him? - Movies StackExchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/102771/how-is-superman-able-to-defeat-kryptonians-who-are-better-trained-and-skilled-th)

However, this idea doesn't seem congruent to me with the idea that Superman will lose his powers when exposed to a red sun. If he can accumulate powers for years, why would his powers immediately vanish when exposed to a red sun? That makes me suppose that the idea that Superman became stronger than Zod isn't official, but a fan's explanation.

Is it canon that Superman became stronger than Zod because he spent more time exposed to our yellow sun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything like that having been established by an official source.

Also, Zod was beaten up by Jor-El back on Krypton, where Earth's yellow sun obviously wasn't a factor. When watching the film myself, it did strike me as counterintuitive that the leading figure in Krypton's militia couldn't handle Krypton's leading scientist in a fistfight. But that's clearly what the film presented to us, so if we accept that premise, then the only explanation needed for Kal defeating Zod too is that he takes after his dad.